# Proof of inequality using AM-GM inequality

Tags: proof-explanation

prove that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge xy + xz + yz$

I tried proving it the way I prove $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2xy$. But it just doesn't seem to work. I tried using AM-GM. Should I be using GM-HM or AM-HM? I really don't know what the problem is and I'd appreciate any help and a full proof explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy$ works here.
\begin{align*}
 x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy \\
y^2+z^2 \geq 2yz\\
z^2+x^2 \geq 2zx
\end{align*}
Adding those 3 inequalities gives
$$ x^2+y^2 + y^2+z^2 +z^2+x^2= 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq 2(xy+yz+zx)$$
So canceling 2 from both sides gives you the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x - y)^2 + (y - z)^2 + (z - x)^2 \geq 0$$

hence

$$2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx \geq 0 $$
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq xy + yz + zx$$

Answer (score 0):

We see that for all real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ that $(x - y)² + (x - z)² + (y - z)² ≥ 0$  by virtue of being a sum of squares. Expanding the left hand side gives  $2x² + 2y² + 2z² - 2xy - 2xz - 2yz ≥ 0$.  Dividing through by two and adding $xy + xz + yz$ to both sides of the inequality gives the desired result 
$x² + y² + z² ≥ xy + xz + yz.$

Comment: thanks but can the inequality be proved using AM-GM inequality generalisation?

Answer (score 0):

Using the AM-GM inequality:
$$
xy + xz + yz \leq \\
\sqrt{x^2y^2} + \sqrt{x^2z^2} + \sqrt{y^2 z^2} \leq\\
\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} + \frac{y^2 + z^2}{2} + \frac{x^2 + z^2}{2} =\\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x:={\rm mid}\{x, y, z\}$, then

$$\sum x^{2}- \sum xy= (y+ z- 2x)^{2}- 3(x- y)(x- z)\geq 0$$